# como hacer un console.log de variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo esta línea de código en JQuery

```
        var n          = $(this).attr("id").lastIndexOf("_") + 1;   
        var id_Req     = $(this).attr("id").substring(n,$(this).attr("id").length);       //Obtengo el ID
        var comentario = $("#tbComentario_" + id_Req);  
        console.log( $( this ).text()); 

        var aprobacion;

        if ($(this).hasClass('aprob') == true)
        { aprobacion = 1; }
        else
        { aprobacion = 0; }

        console.log(aprobacion.text()); 
        if ($.trim(comentario.val()) == "")
        { comentario.parent().addClass("error");
          $("#tbComentario_" + id_Req).focus();

          return false; }
        else
        {
```

quiero saber que me trae el resultado de la variable aprobación a través de un console.log pero me lanza este error

> TypeError: aprobacion.text is not a function

¿A qué se debe ?

Comment: `aprobacion` no es un node al que puedas usar `text()` sino que es un integer (que parece representar un booleano)

Comment: Sólo un apunte adicional a lo comentado por @lois6b : la variable `aprobacion` no es una variable jQuery, es una variable de javascript sin relación alguna con jQuery.

Comment: te aconsejaria tambien que en la condicion uses solo `$(this).hasClass("aprob")` ya que su respuesta es true o false, y el `== true` en este caso es redundante o simplemente `aprobacion = $(this).hasClass("aprob")`

Comment: @OscarGarcia si lo dices por el titulo, seguramente no diga que la variable es de jquery si no que está poniendo el tag en el titulo innecesariamente ^^'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al ser una variable con solo poner:

```
console.log(aprobacion);
```

Debería salirte el resultado correctamente sin necesidad de llamar a una función.

Comment: tu explicacion dice que *"al ser una variable..."* y eso es incorrecto. Al ser una variable de **tipo integer** no puedes usar `text()` en ella porque no existe esa funcion en el prototype de Integer. Pero si la variable es **de tipo Node** entonces si.

Answer (score 5):

Cualquier tipo de objeto o tipo primitivo se puede mostrar simplemente pasando su identificador como parámetro a `console.log`:

```
console.log(identificador);
```

Una cosa a tener en cuenta: Los navegadores modernos (Firefox, Chrome...) tienen una funcionalidad interesante, pero que puede dar lugar a equívocos:

```js
const obj= {
    a:'Un poco de texto',
    b: { t: 'un atributo'},
    b2: 'En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme...',
    texto: 'Hola Mundo'
};

console.log(obj);

obj.b.t='Cambio';
```

Este código muestra lo siguiente en la consola (ojo, no confudir con el emulador de consola de los snippets de Stackoverflow):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, primero muestra una vista previa, creada cuando se llamó `console.log`, pero cuando despliegas los datos verás el valor **actual**.

Si quieres ver exactamente lo que había en ese momento, deberás hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
const obj= {
    a:'Un poco de texto',
    b: { t: 'un atributo'},
    b2: 'En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme...',
    texto: 'Hola Mundo'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null,2));

obj.b.t='Cambio';
```

Estamos usando JSON.strigify indicando que añada una nueva línea y 2 espacios de identación para cada nuevo atributo u objeto anidado. Al ser una representación textual del objeto, no se ve afectada por las modificaciones posteriores