# console.log muestra mal un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer grafos con JavaScript pero me salen muchos errores a la hora de mostrar por consola los arrays, supongamos tengo un array, donde si lo mapeo me imprime bien si lo hago uno por uno, pero si imprimo el array sin mapear me dan valores que no tienen nada que ver con el array, acá un código con un array de objetos

```
23:     array.map((e) => {
24:       console.log(e);
25:        return e;
26:      });
27:      console.log(array);
```

Esta es la respuesta que me da el código de arriba

[image: respuesta]

también veo que en la consola, que en la linea 27 me marca un `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]` pero al abrirlo me salen valores que no se de donde salieron

me pasa así en casi toda la ejecución del código

lo que no entiendo es por que si hago un map del array y hago un console.log de cada ítem si me devuelve los valores correctos, pero no si hago  un console.log(array)

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231316/como-hacer-un-console-log-de-variable-jquery/231343#231343

Comment: Array.map no modifica el array original, crea uno nuevo

Comment: muestra el array original

Comment: Es probable que estes reutilizando la variable `array` o tal vez es global y por eso la diferencia entre lo que dice inicialmente y lo que muestra luego al explandirlo.

Comment: Justo al lado del console.log con el (3), hay un icono con una `( i )`, si pones el cursor ahi verás lo que necesitas... Eso significa que puede existir una diferencia entre la primera vez que hiciste `console.log` y la segunda vez cuando lo expandiste. es decir, alguna parte del código pudo haber mutado la variable luego del `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

En principio estarias queriendo usar el metodo map tal cual si fuese un ciclo for, lo cual no es la idea, ya que map, filter y reduce lo que hacen es devolverte un nuevo array, la idea es mantener el array original "inmutable".
Supongamos que tienes un arreglo de productos como el que sigue:

```
const productos = [
   {
    nombre: "licuadora",
    precio: 1000
   },
   {
    nombre: "cafetera",
    precio: 1500
   },
   {
    nombre: "lavadora",
    precio: 5000
   }
  ]

//y quieres obtener una lista de precios actualizada un 20% (muy usual en mi pais)
// esto podria dartelo:

console.log(productos.map(producto => producto.precio * 1.20));

//pero la idea es usarlo de la siguiente forma:

const preciosActualizados = productos.map(producto => `${producto.nombre} $${producto.precio * 1.20}`)

console.log(preciosActualizados);
```